# Why can't I open my girb2 file using Pygrib?

Tags: python, grib, pygrib

I'm trying to open a grib2 file using pygrib but the error shows like this. Any help would be appreciated as I'm a new Python user

In [2]: debugfile('E:/NASA2/untitled0.py', wdir='E:/NASA2')
File "e:\nasa2\untitled0.py", line 12
grbs = pygrib.open(2011.grb2)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: should be `grbs = pygrib.open('2011.grb2')` but this shouldn't throw a syntax error. could you post your code?

Comment: `2011.grb2`, without quote marks around it, is absolutely a syntax error.

Comment: It can't be a NameError, because it isn't a valid name - it's a floating-point literal followed by a name, with no operation in between.  Just type `2011.grb2` into a Python interpreter and you will get a SyntaxError.

Comment: Actually I didn't have gpygrib module installed but in conda it is showing Packagesnotfound error when I try to install pygrib